# How to permanently set env across every session in fish shell?

Tags: linux, shell, rust-cargo, fish, bin

I install the `cargo` building environment.
I use `cargo install exa` to install `exa` (an alternatives of command `ls`).
Executable file is put in `$HOME/.cargo/bin`.
I use `fish` shell `set -gx PATH $PATH $HOME/.cargo/bin`, and then I can use command `exa` on current session.

But when I open a new session, I cannot execute `exa` unless `set -gx ...` again.

I look in the options `gx`:

```
--global  -g     (Make variable scope global)
--export  -x  (Export variable to subprocess)
```

Does not global mean every session? Could someone help me pls?

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on Stack Overflow should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."*  Your question would likely be better suited for [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackoverflow.com), but please familiarize yourself with that site's rules for posting as well.  I'd recommend deleting it here and moving it over before the mods close it.  It won't count "against" your rep if you do it yourself before downvotes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Doesnot global means every session?

It doesn't. It's "global" as opposed to "local". From [the fish documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variable-scope):

> Global variables are specific to the current fish session, and will never be erased unless explicitly requested by using set -e.

In general, what you want is to just put the `set -gx` into ~/.config/fish/config.fish. That's fish's configuration file.

Fish also has "universal" variables, which *are* stored persistently, but they interact awkwardly with exporting so I wouldn't recommend it.

For $PATH specifically, fish offers the `fish_user_paths` variable that it adds automatically, so you can run

```
set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths $HOME/.cargo/bin
```

once, interactively, and fish will take care of it. This is a universal variable, but fish takes care to add it to $PATH when necessary (for each component it checks if it's already there and such). Do **not** put this into config.fish, or it will add one $HOME/.cargo/bin every time you start a fish, and so it would balloon the variable.

To recap:

- For global variables, put the `set` statement into config.fish
- For universal variables, execute it manually
- For $PATH, use $fish_user_paths for your customizations